# Not able to access parent stack routes from nested stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

This is my Parent navigator.

*AppNavigator.js*

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    SplashScreen: { screen:SplashScreen },
    Login: { screen:Login },
    ForgotPassword: { screen:ForgotPassword },
    RoleOneApp: { screen: RoleOneApp },
    RoleTwoApp: { screen: RoleTwoApp },
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
  },
);
```

This has been used in *App.js* as

```
   <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ dispatch, state: navState })}/>
```

SplashScreen, Login, ForgotPassword are React native screens.

Whereas RoleOneApp and RoleTwoApp are screens with **nested stack navigator.**
The goal is, When app is launched, Splashscreen opens up, assuming user is logged in; depending on the user role(which is stored using AsyncStorage) we will navigate the user to 'RoleOneApp' or 'RoleTwoApp'

*RoleOneApp.js*

```
import RoleOneAppNavigator from './RoleOneAppNavigator';

class RoleOneApp extends React.PureComponent {

  static router = RoleOneAppNavigator.router;

  render() {
    return (<RoleOneAppNavigator navigation={this.props.navigation}/>);
  }
}

export default RoleOneApp;
```

*RoleOneAppNavigator.js*

```
const RoleOneAppNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    roleoneScreen1: {
      screen: SomeScreen1,
    },
    roleoneScreen2: {
      screen: SomeScreen2,
    },
    roleoneScreen3: {
      screen: SomeScreen3,
    },
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    navigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false,
    },
  },
);
```

*RoleTwoApp.js*

```
class RoleTwoApp extends React.PureComponent {

  static router = RoleTwoAppNavigator.router;

  render() {
    return (<RoleTwoAppNavigator navigation={this.props.navigation}/>);
  }
}

export default RoleTwoApp;
```

*RoleTwoAppNavigator.js*

```
const RoleTwoAppNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    roleTwoScreen1: {
      screen: TechScreen1,
    },
    roleTwoScreen2: {
      screen: TechScreen2,
    },
    roleTwoScreen3: {
      screen: TechScreen3,
    },
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    navigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false,
    },
  },
);
```

Now let's say this happens

app launch -> Now the user is in Splash Screen.
SplashScreen: in splash screen we did replaceRoute('RoleOneApp')
RoleOneApp(screen: SomeScreen1)

the problem now is, how can i navigate to Login, ForgotPassword screen from here.
if I try to navigate I'm getting error, Please use one of the route in RoleOneAppNavigator.

> "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
>
> "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.15",
>
> "react-redux": "5.0.5",
>
> "redux": "3.6.0",

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I am stuck on the same issue

Comment: Not yet @dogwasstar